# A $100$ page book has $200$ printing errors randomly distributed ...

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

A $100$ page book has $200$ printing errors randomly distributed throughout. What is the probability that one of the pages is error free?

Consider $$\sum _{i=1}^{100}x_i = 200$$ where each $x_i$ can take integer values from $0$ to $200$. This gives a total of $\binom{299}{99}$ possible ways in which the errors can be distributed in the book. Is it sufficient to now obtain the result as $$\sum_{i=1}^{99}p(i)$$ where $p(i)$ is the probability that exactly $i$ pages are error free?

Comment: Exactly $1$ or at least $1$?

Comment: "What is the probability that one of the pages is error free?" is how the problem was stated. I would assume it means at least $1$.

Comment: @jess77 Is it one specific page, like page 5 ?

Comment: @ jess 77 I don't know whether this should be done by the method of Poisson distribution but see what you think of my solution below.

Comment: Hint: look at the coupon problem, discussed in many posts here. "A coupon collector collects 200 coupons. Each coupon bears a number from 1 to 100. What is the probability that he does not have all 100 possible numbers?"

Answer (score 1):

Its a possions distribution

$P= \lambda^x * e^(-\lambda)/x!$ take $\lambda$$=200/100=2$ and $x=0$ you will get the solution around 13%.

Comment: Can we get exactly same answer with Binomial Distribution?